# How to pass music from a streaming service into HTML5 <audio> element?

Tags: javascript, spotify, html5-audio, web-audio-api

first post here! I'm kind of a noob in JS but I'm working to improve. So, I'm building [this](https://roy-05.github.io/audio-visualizer) audio visualizer using vanilla JS. I still need to work on the CSS but I'm satisfied with it right now - It can decently visualize FFT data for a preloaded song (taken from Free Music Archive)

I now want to **connect a streaming service like *Spotify* to the visualizer so that the music from the streaming service is visualized**. But I'm not exactly sure how to go about doing that. I'm using the Web Audio API to analyze the sound.

I would really appreciate it if someone could provide some direction in going about this, thank you!

**Note**: Site DOES NOT work on mobile yet, sorry.

Comment: very cool visualization!

Comment: This SDK must not be used in commercial projects without Spotify's prior written approval. Hire someone.

Comment: @StackSlave So this is a personal project that I have no intention to monetize. Can I still use the SDK?

Comment: @roy05 is you demo/project on github?

Comment: @AnthumChris Yeah it is [here](https://github.com/Roy-05/audio-visualizer/)!

Comment: This SDK must not be used in commercial projects without Spotify's prior written approval. https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spotify uses [Encrypted Media Source Extensions](https://labs.spotify.com/2019/03/25/building-spotifys-new-web-player/) (see [*Building Spotify's New Web Player*](https://labs.spotify.com/2019/03/25/building-spotifys-new-web-player/)) and I'm not sure if they openly let us access their protected music.  Would be great if they do and anyone can find out how.  [Media Source Extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Source_Extensions_API) is a good option for feeding encoded audio (Opus, MP3, etc) chunks to `<audio>` programmatically for the browser to decode them. I would consider investigating music services that provide free music like BandCamp or Soundcloud.

MSE container support varies by browser, and you can check with

```
MediaSource.isTypeSupported('audio/webm; codecs="opus"');
MediaSource.isTypeSupported('audio/aac; codecs="opus"');
MediaSource.isTypeSupported('audio/mp4; codecs="opus"');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd need to use something like the Spotify Web API.

A quick start guide can be found here:

https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/quick-start/

If you want an example, here is another open source project that seems to have done what you're trying to do:

https://github.com/jamescastells/jamescastells.github.io